# Редирект .htaccess

Tags: apache, веб-программирование, .htaccess, редирект

Как установить редирект с помощью .htaccess с главной страницы `/` на внутреннюю `/v2`? Как это сделать так, чтобы и с `/index.php` шел редирект на `/v2`? При этом в корень сайта установлена Joomla.

Попытка установить редирект так:

```
Redirect / http://site.ru/v2
```

приводит к бесконечным переадресациям, которые останавливаются примерно на

```
http://site.ru/v2/v2/v2/v2/v2/v2
```

При этом перестает открываться `http://site.ru/v2`, даже если обратиться к ней напрямую.

В `/v2` лежит самописный сайтик, т.е. эта часть Jooml'ой не управляется.

Comment: RewriteEngine on?

Comment: Подобного рода ответы оформляются как комментарии к вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил таким образом:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^$ /v2/ [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v2/ [L,QSA]
```